# What are functions of "zu den" used in these two sentences?

Tags: grammar-identification

"Schließlich zählt die Himmelsscheibe, die 1999 von zwei Raubgräbern auf dem Mittelberg bei Nebra (Thüringen) geborgen wurde und die seit 2002 im Landesmuseum für Vorgeschichte in Halle aufbewahrt wird, zu den herausragenden archäologischen Funden der letzten Jahrzehnte weltweit. Und zu den am besten erforschten.
https://www.welt.de/geschichte/article220304666/Himmelsscheibe-von-Nebra-Verzerrte-Beweise-oberflaechliche-Analysen-selektive-Zitate.html

Comment: "zu etwas zählen" means to belong amongst something: the disc belongs to the set of most extraordinary archaeological finds of the past decades. And to the best researched ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are dealing here with the expression "**zu** etwas **zählen**" (to count for or belong to something). The problem with the original text is the long relative clause that tears this expression apart:

> Schließlich **zählt** die Himmelsscheibe, die 1999 von zwei Raubgräbern auf dem Mittelberg bei Nebra (Thüringen) geborgen wurde und die seit 2002 im Landesmuseum für Vorgeschichte in Halle aufbewahrt wird, **zu** den herausragenden archäologischen Funden der letzten Jahrzehnte weltweit. Und **zu** den am besten erforschten.

It would have been stilistically better to write something like:

> Die Himmelsscheibe, die … geborgen wurde und die … aufbewahrt wird, **zählt** schließlich **zu** den herausragenden archäologischen Funden der letzten Jahrzehnte weltweit und **zu** den am besten erforschten.

So, the essence is:

> Die Himmelsscheibe **zählt zu** den herausragenden und (**zu** den) am besten erforschten Funden.

Comment: Is the zu in  "zu den am besten erforschten"  part of verb expression zu etwas zählen ?  Even though it's another sentence.

Comment: @JohnLamb, yes it is. It's actually not another sentence (even though the author arranged it like that) but the enumeration of two things to which something belongs. The structure is: "Etwas **zählt zu** A und **zu** B." It's the same in English: "Something **belongs to** A and **to** B."